# Kubernetes: Backup to FTP

Tags: backup, ftp, kubernetes, minio

I want to backup a Kubernetes cluster using velero. Unfortunately I only have access to FTP backup storage. My idea is to start minio in the cluster and have the FTP location mounted in its data directory.

Has anyone an idea how I could achieve this in a Kubernetes and not too cheaty way? Or is this just a very stupid idea?

Comment: How will you restore?

Comment: In case of a disaster, I would start a new cluster using ansible and bring up my core infrastructure using flux. Then I would be able to restore a backup.